# Symfony 2 - UrlGenerator::doGenerate is called before listener

Tags: exception, authentication, symfony, listener, redirect

I want to add to the context a parameter, so when login is called I can use it in the route (similar to `_locale`).
I can add this piece of code in `HttpUtils.php` (as `resetLocale`), but i don't find it very clean. The reason I need it is the firewall redirection to the login controller, which I would like to have in its route a customized parameter.

My problem is that my listener is called after `UrlGenerator::doGenerate` is called, so I get a `MissingMandatoryParametersException`.

Here is my `config.yml` relevant code:

```
services:
    mycompany.demobundle.listener.request:
        class: MyCompany\DemoBundle\RequestListener
        arguments: [@router, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried manipulating the `priority` option?

```
tags:
   - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 0, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Comment: Just did, it doesn't help - still get the same exception.

Comment: Ok, with `priority: 100000` it works, I guess it is possible to have a lower priority and it will still work.
I tried to print some debugging messages from my listener and from the UrlGenerator, but find it quite hard to follow. Anyway, now it works, thanks!

Comment: Actually I have just checked... very wiered.
When I give `priority: 64`, it works fine. When I give it 63, it simply skip the login panel and shows the protected page. Don't understand it...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you should use **priority** option it can be from *-255 to 255*